# Port number used by spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I have many spring boot app pushed on PCF (Pivotal Cloud Foundry). Just for my understanding I have some question. I can see the default port used by embedded tomcat is 8080 for all the apps. So how is this managed by PCF because generally only 1 app can run on a single port with non PCF project?

Answer (score 4):

Each application runs in a container as a "guest" process on its own "guest" virtual network. The services on the host which manage the containers associate to each container an external port on the host and directs inbound traffic on its external interface at a given port to the appropriate container, with its virtual network and port 8080. PCF will soon allow an application to use multiple ports. For more on the container technology in PCF, see here: https://www.cloudfoundry.org/cloud-foundry-containers-difference-warden-docker-garden/. There is a section at the very end that goes into more detail about how the networking works.